# mvc 4 url custom routing issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, asp.net-mvc-routing

i have an action which takes two parameters but when action is called, parameters are displayed in the url as query string like this:

```
localhost:34795/Verification?DepartmentID=3&SubDepartmentID=2
```

I know that using custom url route i can change this to like this:

localhost:34795/Verification/3/2

but i am unable to do this i added this code to Globas.asax but no outcome till"

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute( "Blog", // Route name 
            "Verification/{DepartmentID}/{SubDepartmentID}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Verification", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }  // Parameter defaults
        );

        //routes.MapRoute(
        //    "Default",                                              // Route name
        //    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
        //    new { controller = "TestDetails", action = "GetSubDepartmentID", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        //);
    }


    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
    }
}
```

i did this way but nothing happened, what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post your view code? How are you submitting your view form?

Comment: @ckv I am redirecting from home controller using Redirect.Action Function..here is the line of code:
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Verification", new RouteValueDictionary { { "DepartmentID", result.DepartmentId }, { "SubDepartmentID", result.SubdepartmentId } });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the solution, after thorough debugging i realized that in asp.net mvc 4 it creates some classes by default in application Shared directory and there for registering routes application was calling this method:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
    }
```

You see here its calling RegisterRoutes method which is in RouteConfig.cs file which means in RouteConfig class its not calling the method of Global.asax, this was the issue and i got mad solving it and at last this result i got and got thing to work.

Here is my RouteConfig.cs code which solved the issue and make things work:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute("home", "", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Verification",                                              // Route name
            "Verification/{DepartmentID}/{SubDepartmentID}",                           // URL with parameters
            new
            {
                controller = "Verification",
                action = "Index",
                DepartmentID = UrlParameter.Optional,
                SubDepartmentID = UrlParameter.Optional
            } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
routes.MapRoute("Blog",
    "Verification/{DepartmentID}/{SubDepartmentID}",
    new {
        controller = "Verification",
        action = "Index",
        DepartmentID = UrlParameter.Optional,
        SubDepartmentID = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

Then in your `Index` function in VerificationController:

```
public ActionResult Index(int DepartmentID, int SubDepartmentID)
```

Comment: I have did this way but its not working url is showing same way..:(